# How to convert csv to rosbag?

Tags: csv, ros, data-conversion

I have a csv file that I want to convert into rosbag as I am trying to use a package written in ROS. The goal is to perform sensor fusion using an extended kalman filter and my csv file has information of IMU and GPS data.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your CSV?

Comment: Create a python script to read the CSV and publish on rostopics

Comment: Do you timestamp data for when it was recorded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple steps:

**1. Read in the data from the CSV file.**

There are a number of ways to do this in Python but I prefer using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_csv_file.csv')
```

This loads the data as a Pandas dataframe that you can read off columns as`df['timestamp']` which can then be indexed like an array.

**2. Populate ROS messages and write to rosbag**

There is a nice Python API for rosbag. I don't know exactly what the data elements are in your CSV file so I will leave the message population up to you, but it looks something like:

```
import rospy
import rosbag
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu, NavSatFix

with rosbag.Bag('output.bag', 'w') as bag:
    for row in range(df.shape[0]):
        timestamp = rospy.Time.from_sec(df['timestamp'][row])
        imu_msg = Imu()
        imu_msg.header.stamp = timestamp

        # Populate the data elements for IMU
        # e.g. imu_msg.angular_velocity.x = df['a_v_x'][row]

        bag.write("/imu", imu_msg, timestamp)

        gps_msg = NavSatFix()
        gps_msg.header.stamp = timestamp

        # Populate the data elements for GPS

        bag.write("/gps", gpu_msg, timestamp)
```

Note that there seem to be other GPS message types you can use, e.g. from the [gps_common](http://wiki.ros.org/gps_common) package. `/imu` and `/gps` are the topic names and you can name them as desired.

Comment: I tried this but what is the correct way to generate a CMakeLists.txt and run this?

Comment: You create a ROS package using `catkin_create_pkg` command and write a rospy node with the above code-snippet. `catkin_create_pk` creates CMakeLists.txt for you. Why are you looking to create CMakelists.txt from scratch?

Comment: what are all the different fields that someone can populate for the Imu() object? I can't find the documentation or code for it.

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 It is quite some time ago when you asked that question but you can find the fields of the Imu() object (and all other standard messages of ROS) [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html).